# Bigger request to server vs. more javascript on client

Tags: javascript, performance, http

What is the better solution, when performance/UX is important: Send a bigger (more data) HTTP PUT request, or delete unnecessary data with javascript on client and send a smaller request?

Comment: Depends on the number of times the js is loaded and frequency of web requests sent.

Comment: And the processing speed / memory of the device compared to the network speed / reliability.

Comment: Performance of what? Page load time? PUT request time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the time over the wire is going to be more costly than local processing time, so if you are worried about performance you should probably spend the time locally to delete the extra data and then not have to upload that unnecessary data to the server.

I would recommend doing some performance testing, though, to have empirical data to back up your decision. Get the time before you delete the data and then the time after and measure how long it takes and then do the same measurement to see how long it takes to send the big request versus the little request to the server. Then you can make a data-driven decision.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't really want a 'chatty' conversation with the server. If the data already exists on the client-side update that... then send it back to the server.

However, if the data is on the server-side and not on the client-side, best sending a command to the server to update it that end, and not pull the object client-side, manipulate and send-back (that is too chatty)